# Bitbucket deployment ssh key for all repos in organisation

Tags: bitbucket

We have about 30 projects in organisation on Bitbucket. To deploy them we need to add deployment ssh key for each repo in it.
Is there a way to save time and add deployment ssh key for all repos in organisation at once?